# C# mocking and testing WebAPI to test if query string binds to model properly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, moq

I am writing some simple WebAPI controller unit tests and I am a bit confused how to setup the test to use a query string of my choice and let the model binder do its thing when I call the controller action. The controller is a GET request and the query string is simple like `?statusid=1&number=075454545`, etc...

```
_smsNotificationController = new SmsNotificationController(_mockedService.Object, _mockedHttpService.Object, _mockedloggingService.Object);
_smsNotificationController.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl + paramaters);
```

The next step I can Mock the Controller by passing in a model that I have constructed

```
var result = await _smsNotificationController.Receipt(new ReceiptModel(){...}());
```

But what I really want is that model to be bound to the `HttpRequestMessage` I created before. So I can change the query string on arrange and do my asserts based on the query string that somebody is sending me instead of the models I assume will be bound.

So this wont work as the model is NULL on the controllers action

```
var result = await _smsNotificationController.Receipt(It.IsAny<ReceiptModel>());
```

How do I trigger model binding based on the HttpRequest?

Comment: `It.IsAny` is used in the moq setup. it is not an actual value to be used when exercising the test. create an actual receipt model and pass that to the method under test. What you describe looks more like in integration test which can be done as an in-memory integration test using test server

Comment: So you mean by doing a in memory server? Is there any way to pass the query string into the default model binder and then I can pass that into the controller without running the server. I just want to test the `flow` as the actual implementations are tested else where.

Comment: Testing the flow means testing how the different units integrate with each other. You are also basically testing the framework not your code.

Comment: Yea.. and I understand that I should "trust" the framework... but somehow I feel incomplete if I don't do this test.. :D

Comment: While it is possible to do what you want, my opinion is that the necessary setup required to do that is a lot of unnecessary added work. Check this article if you want to venture down that path. http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/

Comment: Well you said it in the first comment and now again.. I must use the in memory server... OK (I wanted to be lazy).. looks like allot of work but its not that bad .. I have seen much larger test rigging up -- compared to your link that is not that much really. Thanks for the quick responses. I am going to do that now. PS - Nice weather in Trinidad? I need to move there and do C# too :D

Comment: That is not really doing what I wanted to do either.. I think I will just give up on that for now ;(

Comment: Do you use a custom model binder? in this case you need to write tests against that. If you don't, it would be quite difficult to simulate the real scenario as binding may fail due to : web.config setting; whether you run in OWIn or IIS; what TLS hardening is applied on the server; the format of the request etc.

Comment: I forgot about this but I think the tests were actually passing - ie not binding.. doh. Because I forgot to put [FromUri] on the method. But once I realised that I re wrote all my tests.. I should actually do a quick test and see if the built in binders work now.. that is all I wanted. What I thought was a false positive (or me being thick) may have actually been a real test error :D